# Como crear un programa que multiplique matrices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intento hacer un programa que multiplique dos matrices dadas por el usuario. Lo que he logrado hacer es esto:

```
def CrearMatrizA (m, n):
    return [[0.0 for j in range (n)] for i in range (m)]
def CrearMatrizB (m, n):
    return [[0.0 for k in range (n)] for p in range (m)]
def CrearMatrizC (m, n):
    return [[0.0 for x in range (n)] for y in range (m)]



def EntrarDatos (matriz):
    m = len(matriz)
    n = len(matriz[0])
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range (n):
            matriz [i] [j] = float(input( "m["+ str(i) + "][" + str(j) + "]?"))
    return

def EntrarDatosC (matriz):
    m = len(A)
    n = len (B[0])
    for x in range (m):
        for y in range (n):
            matriz [x][y] = MultiplicarMatriz (A, B, C)
    return

def MostrarMatriz(matriz):
    m = len(matriz)
    n = len(matriz[0])
    for i in range (m):
        for j in range (n):
            print (matriz [i][j])
        print
    return


def MultiplicarMatriz(A, B, C):
    m1 = len(A)
    n1 = len(A[0])
    m2 = len(B)
    n1 = len(B[0])
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for p in range (m2):
        for i in range (m1):
            for j in range (n1): 
                for k in range (m2):
                    l = A[i][j] * B[k][p]
                    C[x][y] = C[x][y] + l
                    j = j + 1
                    k = k + 1
        i = i + 1
        x = x + 1
        j = 1
        k = 1
    p = p + 1
    y = y + 1
    x = 1
    i = 1
    return 


def main():
    m1 = int(input("Digite la cantidad de filas de la primera matriz: "))
    n1 = int(input("Digite la cantidad de columnas de la primera matriz: "))
    m2 = int(input("Digite la cantidad de filas de la segunda matriz: "))
    n2 = int(input("Digite la cantidad de columnas de la segunda matriz: "))

    if((m1, m2, n1, n2 > 0) and (m1 == n2)):
        '''hay un problema cuando todos son cero'''
        A = CrearMatrizA(m1, n1)
        EntrarDatos(A)
        B = CrearMatrizB(m2, n2)
        EntrarDatos (B)
        C = CrearMatrizC(m1, n2)
        C = MultiplicarMatriz(A, B, C)

        MostrarMatriz(A)
        MostrarMatriz(B)
        MostrarMatriz (C)   
    else:
       print("Las matrices no son multiplicables")    
    return
```

Tengo un millón de errores ya que soy nuevo en esto, pero lo principal es lo siguiente:

- como hacer que en la función MultiplicarMatrices el programa reconozca cada uno de los subíndices que quiero usar?
- cual es el dato que me va a retornar MultiplicarMatrices?
- como crear la matriz producto?
- es necesario crear una función para crear cada una de las matrices que se van a utilizar en el programa?

Se que es mucho y probablemente mi código no tiene mucho sentido, pero agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te estas liando algo entre tanto índice... XD. Vamos a ver si podemos aclarar algunas cosas:

- A la hora de definir la función para crear las matrices no es necesario (de hecho no tiene sentido) usar una función para cada matriz, con una basta.
- Puedes incluso crear la matriz según el usuario introduce los datos, no tienes porque inicializarla primero con valores que luego vas a modificar. Es decir, el input puede perfectamente ir dentro de la sentencia de compresión de listas que usas para inicializar la matriz.
- La línea `if(m1, m2, n1, n2 > 0)` no hace lo que piensas. Tu quieres comprobar que ninguno de los números sea 0, pero en realidad estas solo comprobando en valor de `m1`, si `m1` no es 0 (False) se evalua como `True` sin importar que los otros sean 0 o no. La línea debería ser:

  `if m1>0 and m2>0 and n1>0 and n2>0 and m1 == n2`

  Otra opción es usar la función preconstruida [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all) que retorna `True` si todas las condiciones se cumplen y `False` en caso contrario:

  `if all((m1>0,m2>1,n1>1,n2>1, m1 == n2))`
- En Python no es necesario que las funciones retornen algo obligatoriamente, si no lo necesitas no tienes porque usar el `return` al final de cada una de ellas. Por otro lado las funciones y métodos de clase se suelen nombrar empezando por minúscula, reservando los nombres que empiezan por mayúscula para nombrar las clases. Es solo una convención, no un error en sí.
- La matriz que se encarga de multiplicar no tiene porque recibir la matriz de salida ya construida, puedes hacer que se cree dentro de la función y que retorne la matriz resultado quedando el código mas encapsulado, aunque tu forma también es válida.
- El lio más gordo creo que lo tienes en la propia función que multiplica las matrices. Piensa que es lo que se hace al multiplicar una matriz, necesitamos recorrer cada fila de la primera matriz tantas veces como columnas tiene la segunda. Eso son dos `for` anidados. Para poder guardar los datos en la matriz de salida necesitamos ir sumando el resultado de ir multiplicando los elemntos obtenidos con los indices anteriores para lo cual necesitamos otro `for` anidado más:

  ```
  def multiplicarMatriz(A, B):
      filasA = len(A)
      columnasA = len(A[0])
      columnasB = len(B[0])

      C=[[0 for j in range(columnasB)] for i in range(filasA)]

      for i in range(filasA):
          for j in range(columnasB):
              for k in range(columnasA):
                  C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
      return C
  ```

  Esto en realidad se puede reducir bastante usando compresión de listas y [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

  ```
  def multiplicarMatriz(A, B):
      return [[sum(x * B[i][col] for i,x in enumerate(fila)) for col in range(len(B[0]))] for fila in A]
  ```

  O se puede usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

  ```
  def multiplicarMatriz(A, B):
      return [[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(filA,colB)) for colB in zip(*B)] for filA in A]
  ```

El código podría quedar algo así:

```
def crearMatriz(filas, columnas):
   return [[float(input("m[{}][{}]?: ".format(i, j))) for j in range(columnas)] for i in range(filas)]

def mostrarMatriz(matriz):
    for fila in matriz:
        for n in fila:
            print("{:10.2f} ".format(n), end='') 
        print()
    print()

def multiplicarMatriz(A, B):
    return [[sum(x * B[i][col] for i,x in enumerate(fila)) for col in range(len(B[0]))] for fila in A]


def main():
    filasA = int(input("Digite la cantidad de filas de la primera matriz: "))
    columnasA= int(input("Digite la cantidad de columnas de la primera matriz: "))
    filasB = int(input("Digite la cantidad de filas de la segunda matriz: "))
    columnasB = int(input("Digite la cantidad de columnas de la segunda matriz: "))

    if all((filasA>0,columnasA>1,filasB>1,columnasB>1, columnasA == filasB)):
        A = crearMatriz(filasA, columnasA)
        B = crearMatriz(filasB, columnasB)
        C = multiplicarMatriz(A, B)

        print('\nMatriz A:')
        mostrarMatriz(A)
        print('Matriz B:')
        mostrarMatriz(B)
        print('Matriz AxB:')
        mostrarMatriz(C)     
    else:
       print("Las matrices no son multiplicables")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

La función encargada de mostrar la matriz la he modificado un poco para que en vez de imprimir los numeros uno detrás de otro los imprima en un formato algo más parecido a una matriz y alineados con la posibilidad de mostrar 7 dígitos enteros y dos decimales por cada dato. Es una salida básica, se puede mejorar. Por otro lado, en vez de usar m y n para nombrar las variables he intnetado usar algunas más descriptivas como `columnaB`, `filaA`, etc para que sea más fácil seguir la lógica.

La munción `multiplicarMatriz` es la que usas list comprehensions y `enumerate`, puedes intercambiarla por cualquiera de las otras dos versiones sin modificar nada más. Solo es un código mostrando un poco las ideas que he intentado explicar, no se si se me ha escapado algo...

Ejemplo de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]