# Multiplicar listas de listas y matrices de NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matrices, numpy

Estoy tratando de realizar la multiplicación de matrices con python.
El objetivo del programa es tener tres matrices como parámetros: A,B y res (matriz de resultados) que se completará con el resultado de multiplicar las matrices representadas por las listas de listas. El programa debe aceptar tanto listas de listas como matrices de NumPy.

Escribí el siguiente código:

```
'''
multMatrices(a, b, res): Completa los elementos de res
con el resultado de multiplicar las matrices representadas por 
las listas de listas a y b.
'''    
def multMatrices(A, B, res):
    filas_A = len(A)
    cols_A = len(A[0])
    filas_B = len(B)
    cols_B = len(B[0])
    
    res = matrizCeros()
    
    if cols_A != filas_B:
      print("No es posible multiplicar las matrices. Dimensiones incorrectas.")
      return
    
    # Se crean las dimensiones de la matriz
    # Lss dimensiones deben ser filas_A x cols_B
    res = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(filas_A)]
    #print(res)   #Cuidado con este print
    
    
    #preguntar por las matrices de numpy con instance 
    if isinstance(A,np.matrix) and isinstance(B,np.matrix):        
        #res = np.matmul(A, B)
        np.copyto(res,np.matmul(A, B))
    else:
        
        #Si isinstance devuelve False, se ejecuta esta sección original
        for i in range(filas_A):
            for j in range(cols_B):
                for k in range(cols_A):
                    res[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
```

Cuándo pruebo con listas de listas el programa funciona, pero no con matrices de NumPy:

```
C = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
D = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
E = matrizCeros()
X = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Y = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Z = matrizCeros()
print("Resultado Mult:",multMatrices(C, D, E))
print("Resultado Mult:",multMatrices(X, Y, Z))

#Resultados:

Resultado Mult: [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
No es posible multiplicar las matrices. Dimensiones incorrectas.
Resultado Mult: None
```

No he logrado identificar que estoy haciendo mal. Agradezco la realimentación brindada.

Comment: En lugar de convertir las matrices en listas para multiplicar, porque no conviertes las listas en matrices?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como crear un programa que multiplique matrices?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61810/como-crear-un-programa-que-multiplique-matrices)

Answer (score 2):

Tu código puede ser simplificado a lo siguiente, y acepta listas de listas, arrays matrices, conviertiendo cualquier entrada que reciba en un array de numpy.

```
import numpy as np

def multMatrices(A,B, res=None):
    A = np.asarray(A)
    B = np.asarray(B)

    if A.shape[-1] != B.shape[0]:
        print('No es posible multiplicar las matrices. Dimensiones incorrectas.')
        return None

    if res and res.shape == (A.shape[0], B.shape[-1]):
        np.copyto(res, np.matmul(A,B))
        return res

    return np.matmul(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para multiplicar matrices **numpy** nos ofrece la posibilidad de crear una **matriz de ceros** y después darle los valores.

##### Creando una matriz de ceros:

```
# Matriz de ceros de 3 x 3 de tipo int
unaMatrizVacia = np.zeros((3,3), int)
```

El resultado de una matriz de ceros:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

#### Multiplicación de matrices recibiendo por parámetro matrices o listas de listas

Creamos la función con una `matrizFinal` que tendrá el tamaño según la dimensión de matriz que ingresa.

```
import numpy as np

mat1 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
mat2 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]

mat3 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
mat4 = [[1,2],[3,4]]

mat5 = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]) # tipo matriz
mat6 = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]) # tipo matriz


def multiplicarMatrices(matriz1, matriz2):
    matrizFinal = np.zeros((len(matriz1), len(matriz1)), int)
    if isinstance(matriz1, np.matrix) and isinstance(matriz2, np.matrix):
        matriz1 = np.asarray(matriz1)
        matriz2 = np.asarray(matriz2)
    if len(matriz1[0]) != len(matriz2):
        return "Las matrices no se pueden multiplicar"
    else:
        for i in range(len(matriz1)):
            for j in range(len(matriz2[0])):
                for k in range(len(matriz2)):
                    matrizFinal[i][j] += matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j]
        return matrizFinal


print("mat1 * mat2: \n", multiplicarMatrices(mat1, mat2))
print("mat3 * mat4: \n", multiplicarMatrices(mat3, mat4))
print("mat5 * mat6: \n", multiplicarMatrices(mat5, mat6))
```

`matrizFinal = np.zeros((len(matriz1), len(matriz1)), int)` nos creara una matriz para poder insertarlo los valores extraídos de las listas.

`isinstance(matriz1, np.matrix) and isinstance(matriz2, np.matrix)` Verifica si las matrices que ingresan por parámetro son de tipo `matriz`. En caso de ser de tipo matriz las convierte a listas de listas.

`return matrizFinal` la salida final es una matriz

```
mat1 * mat2: 
 [[3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]]

mat3 * mat4 : 
 [[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]

mat5 * mat6: 
 [[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.