# multiplicar listas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano. Tengo el siguiente codigo que debe modificar la lista cambiando el signo de todos los números que contiene.El programa debe cambiar cada uno de los signos que tiene asignado dichos elementos que forman la lista. Cambiando los signos negativos por los positivos y viceversa.

He probado de dos formas pero no he podido con ninguna:

```
import operator
def change_sign(numbers):
    signo = [-1]
    lista_multi = list(map(operator.mul, numbers, signo))

numbers = [4, 7, 0, 2, 3, -10, -412, -1453, 614, -515]




def change_sign(numbers):
resultado = [numbers * -1]
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer un bucle que itere por los índices de la lista, y para cada índice haga `numbers[i] *= -1`. Eso alterará la lista recibida como parámetro, cambiando cada elemento por el resultado de multiplicarle por -1. Dicho sea de paso, no es buena idea que una función altere la lista que recibe como parámetro, y lo mejor sería que en cambio creara otra lista con el resultado deseado y retornara esa otra lista. Lee bien la especificación del problema no vaya a ser que te pida lo segundo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, el problema no especifica nada

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como crear un programa que multiplique matrices?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61810/como-crear-un-programa-que-multiplique-matrices)

Answer (score 2):

Una forma más común y menos liosa que usar una lambda es usar comprensiones de lista, que son para lo que están pensadas.

```
In [1]: lista = [1,2,3,-4,-5,-6]                                                                                     

In [2]: lista_reversed = [ numero * -1 for numero in lista]                                                          

In [3]: lista_reversed                                                                                               
Out[3]: [-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Las comprensiones de lista son una forma de simplificar la alteración y modificación de listas. Es sencillo cuando pillas el concepto. Basicamente loopeas la lista y por cada elemento actualizas el valor de la variable `numero`, lo multiplicas por -1 y lo añades a un nuevo elemento de la lista `lista_reversed`.

Se "lee" de la siguiente forma

```
lista_nueva = [ numero multiplicado por -1 por cada numero de la lista original]
```

Si no lo entiendes comenta y lo intento explicar de otra forma

Answer (score 1):

mi recomendación es que hagas un bucle que vaya uno a uno los elementos de la lista y los cambie por el mismo numero multiplicado por -1, de ese modo los elementos de la lista todos terminarán con el signo contrario al que tenían antes del bucle.

aquí hice un ejemplo de como funcionaría:

```py
    lista = [2,45,5132,-123,325,-1325,-134]

    for i in range(len(lista)): 
        lista[i]= lista[i]*-1

    print(lista)
```

en ese bucle el numero "i" va aumentando hasta que llegue al largo de la lista llamada en este caso "lista". luego en cada ciclo cambia el elemento posicionado en el espacio "i" de la lista y lo reemplaza por el mismo numero pero multiplicado por -1.

espero te sirva a completar el ejercicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion `lambda`, dicha función tomara como parámetro un dato en este caso `numero` y en este ejemplo te retornara dicho numero multiplicado por **-1**, seria algo como:
`lambda numero:numero*-1`
y para toda la lista deberás usar la funcion `map` para mapear todos los datos y retornarlos con los signos contrarios, entonces la funcion quedaria :

```py
def change_sign(numbers):
    lista_numbers = list(map(lambda numero:numero*-1,numbers))
    print(lista_numbers)
```

le pasarias como parametro uns lista de numeros,
**Ejemplo:**

```py
change_sign([-9,8,-6,2,-3])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto su código expuesto, está bien. El incoveniente de este, es que nunca he empleado la función lambda, pero igualmente muchas gracias, porque me ha sido de ayuda para futuras ocasiones