# Multiplicar listas por float: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

```
  1 lista = [2, 6, 8, 10, 23, 9, 7, 1, 68, 17, 3]
  2 suma = sum(lista)
  3 print(suma)
  4 mult = 7*lista
  5 print(mult)
  6 suma2 = sum(mult)
  7 print(suma2)
```

----> 8 mult2 = lista*2.5
9 print(mult2)
10 suma3 = sum(mult2)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como crear un programa que multiplique matrices?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61810/como-crear-un-programa-que-multiplique-matrices)

Answer (score 2):

En Python, una lista multiplicada por un entero produce una nueva lista compuesta de *ene* repeticiones de la primera. Mira este ejemplo:

```
lista = [2, 6, 8]
print(lista * 2) => [2, 6, 8, 2, 6, 8]
```

Esto es útil pues normalmente uno quiere inicializar listas con un número de elementos en cero (por ejemplo): `[0] * 7` crea una lista de 7 ceros.

Por tanto, multiplicar una lista por un float no tiene sentido y probablemente no es lo que buscas.

#### Multiplicar los elementos de una lista

Si lo que quieres es multiplicar cada elemento de una lista por un cierto valor, la manera usual de hacerlo es con comprensión de listas:

```
nueva_lista = [x * factor for x in lista]
```

Por ejemplo, multiplicar cada elemento por dos:

```
lista = [2, 6, 8]
nueva_lista = [x * 2 for x in lista]
print(nueva_lista)
```

produce:

```
[4, 12, 16]

Process finished with exit code 0
```