# Como lograr un resultado de una operacion de mutiplicacion entre elementos de una sublist y luego sumar el produc entre sublistas

Tags: python, lista

soy nuevo en esto de programacion y les agradeceria si me pueden aclarar y ayudar con lo siguiente.

De acuerdo a un puntaje inicial de 501 puntos.

Estoy tratando de lograr recibir 6 inputs, donde 3 primeros correspondan a p1 y los 3 ultimos a p2.

Cada uno de los 6 input que corresponden a un multiplicador y puntaje (ejem: 3 10), donde 3 es el multiplicador y 10 el puntaje.

Dando vueltas logre lo siguiente

```
p1 = 501
p2 = 501
puntaje[]

while p1 or p2 == 0:   
    puntaje.append(input().split(" "))

    if len(puntaje) == 6:
        puntaje_int = [[int(elem) for elem in lista] for lista in puntaje]
        print(puntaje_int)
        break
```

ejemplo de lo que me entrega la consola ingresando 6 inputs de 3 10 c/u

```
[[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10]]
```

Con el `input` y `append` agrego a lista `puntaje[]` y con `split` separo el multiplicador y el puntaje.

Bueno esto me genero una sublista por cada input que ingreso; aquí es donde necesito de su ayuda, ya que me complique.

¿Cómo logro multiplicar cada una de las sublistas y luego sumarlas? Y, claro, dividirlas de acuerdo al orden ingresado, ya que las 3 primeras son para restarlas a p1 y las otras 3 para restarlas a p2.

Lo que quiero lograr:

```
[[3*10]+[3*10]+[3*10]+[3*10]+[3*10]+[3*10]]

[[30]+[30]+[30]+[30]+[30]+[30]]
```

`p1= 501 - 90`, donde los 90 corresponden a la suma de las 3 primeras sublistas.

`p2 = 501 - 90`, y estos 90 corresponden a la suma de las 3 ultimas sublistas.

Puse len == 6 ya que quiero imprimir el estado de la resta cada 6 inputs (3 para p1 y 3 para p2)

Bueno esa seria mi duda espero que me puedan ayudar sin importar ninguna libreria.

Comment: No entiendo el 120. La suma de las tres primeras sublistas sería 90 ¿no?

Comment: exacto, me traspapele. Ahi lo edite, gracias por el aviso

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como crear un programa que multiplique matrices?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61810/como-crear-un-programa-que-multiplique-matrices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a escribir una función que llamaré `sumaprod()` que espera como parámetro una lista de este estilo:

```
datos = [[3, 10], [5, 20], [2, 15]]
```

y retorna la suma de todos los productos de cada sublista (es decir `3*10+5*20+2*15`). Una vez tengamos esta función aplicarla a parte de tus datos (a los tres primeros o los tres últimos) se resuelve con *slices* como veremos al final.

Para implementar `sumaprod()` voy a mostrar tres alternativas, según qué paradigma de programación sea tu favorito:

- Imperativo (o clásico), usando simples bucles y operaciones aritméticas. Es el estilo típico que seguiría alguien que ya sabe programar en C o Java.
- Funcional, no hay bucles visibles, sino funciones que se pasan como parámetros a otras funciones que son las que iteran. Este estilo es confuso si nunca lo has usado, pero a los matemáticos parece gustarles, y algunos lenguajes de programación se basan por completo en él. Python lo soporta.
- Comprensiones de listas o expresiones generadoras. Son en cierto modo un mix de los dos anteriores. Pueden reemplazar a la programación funcional con una sintaxis más "pythónica" y suelen ser el método preferido por los pythonistas.

### Versión imperativa

```
def sumaprod(lista):
  suma = 0
  for a, b in lista:
    suma += a*b
  return suma

datos = [[3, 10], [5, 20], [2, 15]]
print(sumaprod(datos))  # --> 160
```

No creo que requiera mucha explicación. Al iterar por cada elemento de `lista` se obtiene una sublista con dos elementos, que gracias a la sintaxis `a, b` desempaqueto en dos variables. Basta multiplicarlas y añadir el resultado a lo que había en `suma`.

### Versión funcional

```
from math import prod  # Este import requiere python 3.8 o superior

def sumaprod(lista)
  return sum(map(prod, lista))
```

Este sí requiere quizás un poco más de explicación. La función `sum()` espera un iterable que contenga números y se limita a sumarlos todos. Para proporcionarle a `sum()` el iterable con los números que necesita, usamos `map()`.

`map()` espera como primer parámetro una función y como segundo parámetro un iterable. Lo que hace es ir iterando por el iterable recibido (en este caso `lista`) y a cada elemento del mismo aplicarle la función que recibe como primer parámetro (en este caso `prod`). Va devolviendo los resultados de cada iteración (que son consumidos por `sum()`).

La función `prod()` (disponible en Python3.8+) espera una lista y multiplica todos sus elementos. En este caso la lista que recibirá será de dos elementos.

Así que la cadena de ejecución en realidad sería:

[image: diagrama]

Observa que esta solución tiene la ventaja de que cada sublista podría tener más de 2 elementos y los multiplicaría todos. Para tu caso eso no es necesario, pero es una solución más general.

Si trabajas con python en versión inferior a la 3.8 no tienes `math.prod` pero puedes implementar una versión equivalente con más programación funcional:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def prod(l):
  return reduce(mul, l)
```

(no voy a explicar ésta por no extenderme más)

### Versión con expresiones generadoras

```
def sumaprod(lista):
  return sum(a*b for a, b in lista)
```

Aquí de nuevo usamos `sum()` para sumar números, pero en este caso la secuencia de números a sumar la creamos con una expresión generadora, que evalúa el producto `a*b` para cada pareja de números `a,b` contenida en la `lista`.

Si quieres que la versión sea más genérica y pueda multiplicar sublistas con cualquier número de elementos, nada nos impide mezclar esta expresión generadora con la función `prod` de la solución anterior:

```
def sumaprod(lista):
  return sum(prod(numeros) for numeros in lista)
```

## Uso en tu caso

Tienes:

```
p1 = 501
p2 = 501
puntaje = [[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10]]
```

y basta entonces que hagas:

```
p1 -= sumaprod(puntaje[0:3])
p2 -= sumaprod(puntaje[3:6])
```

La primera expresión resta a `p1` el resultado de aplicar `sumaprod()` sobre los tres primeros elementos de `puntaje`.

La segunda resta a `p2` el resultado de aplicar `sumaprod()` sobre los tres siguientes elementos de `puntaje`.

Comment: Gracias! todo claro, ya con esto puedo seguir con el resto.

Comment: Como tendria que cambiar la funcion para que vaya restando el producto de 1 en 1? y no sume todo y reste todo de golpe.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres. Si crees que puedes explicarte mejor poniendo ejemplos de código puedes abrir una nueva pregunta (y si es necesario referenciar ésta desde la nueva)

Comment: listo realice otra pregunta. Gracias.