# Como puedo restar el producto de una sublista a una variable externa?

Tags: python, lista

necesito algo de ayuda.
Tengo que restar un elemento a la vez de una sublsita a una variable externa.
[Como lograr un resultado de una operacion de mutiplicacion entre elementos de una sublist y luego sumar el produc entre sublistas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493536/como-lograr-un-resultado-de-una-operacion-de-mutiplicacion-entre-elementos-de-un/493548?noredirect=1#comment877504_493548)

```
-abulafia
    Versión imperativa
    def sumaprod(lista):
      suma = 0
      for a, b in lista:
        suma += a*b
      return suma
    
    datos = [[3, 10], [5, 20], [2, 15]]
    print(sumaprod(datos))  # --> 160

    Uso en tu caso
    Tienes:
    
    p1 = 501
    p2 = 501
    puntaje = [[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10],[3, 10]]
    y basta entonces que hagas:
    
    p1 -= sumaprod(puntaje[0:3])
    p2 -= sumaprod(puntaje[3:6])
    La primera expresión resta a p1 el resultado de aplicar sumaprod() sobre los tres primeros elementos de puntaje.
    
    La segunda resta a p2 el resultado de aplicar sumaprod() sobre los tres siguientes elementos de puntaje.
```

En la respuesta que tuve, entendi perfectamente como operaba la funcion, una vez que lo probe en el bucle realizaba la operacion perfectamente, pero ahora terminando el problema me di cuenta que las restas a la variable p1 y p2 tienen que ser individuales, ya que requiero que el bucle termine una vez que llegue a 0 la variable p1 o p2 a medida que ingreso los inputs y no esperar a tener los 6 inputs para que la funcion realice lo indicado.

Para hacerlo mas claro, requiero que a medida que vaya multiplicando las parejas de sublistas, el producto de cada sublista se reste inmediatamente a la variable externa (variables p1 y p2 de acuerdo al orden de las sublistas, elementos [0:3] restan a p1 y elementos [3:6] restarian a p2). Esto para que en caso de que al segundo input el resultado de 0, el bucle termine y no seguir ingresando inputs.

Como indique en la pregunta anterior, no quiero importar nada

Tengo el bucle de esta forma:

```
p1 = 501
p2 = 501

while p1 != 0 or p2 != 0:
    puntaje.append(input().replace("DOUBLE","50").replace("SINGLE","25").replace("BULL","1").replace("NULL","0 0").split(" "))
    puntaje_int = [[int(elem) for elem in lista] for lista in puntaje]
    len_lista = len_lista + 1
    #print(len_lista)'

if len_lista % 6 == 0:
    p1 = abs(p1 - sumaprod(puntaje_int[0:3]))
    p2 = abs(p2 - sumaprod(puntaje_int[3:6]))
    print(puntaje_int)
    print("")
    print(j1,p1)
    print(j2,p2)
    print("")
    del puntaje
    del puntaje_int
    puntaje = []

if p1 == 0:
    print("Gano",jugadores[0]+"! Felicidades")

if p2 == 0:
    print("Gano",jugadores[1]+"! Felicidades")
```

Se agradece la ayuda y consejos.

Comment: No lo entiendo del todo. ¿En el input se meten de todas formas seis parejas de datos separadas por espacios, pero luego quieres que se procesen de una en una? ¿O quieres también que cada input vaya separado (solo un par de datos a multiplicar) y que no se hagan más inputs cuando uno de los puntajes llegue a cero?

Comment: Por cada ronda son 6 inputs, tu me ayudaste a multiplicar cada uno de esos inputs. Ahora que tengo terminado el codigo me di cuenta que cuando ingreso un input y unas de esas 2 variables da 0 exactamente con ese input, el ciclo no para, ya que espera a que se ingresen las 3 para realizar la operacion. Esto se debe a que la funcion, primero multiplica cada una de ella, luego las suma con las otras sublistas y despues resta a la variable. Por lo que ahora necesito que al tener un producto este se reste inmediatamente a la variable segun el parametro indicado.

Comment: osea se resten de 1 en 1 y no como grupo de a 3

Comment: Que los 6 inputs se resten de 1 en 1 y no como grupo de a 3 para cada variable. El producto de los elementos 0, 1 y 2, en vez de sumarse entre ellos y restar, estos se resten individualmente a p1 y lo mismo para los elementos 3,4 y 5 a p2.

Comment: ¿puedes escribir un ejemplo de cómo sería lo que el usuario teclea al ejecutar el programa? Yo no veo como es que al hacer `split()` del input te van a salir parejas de valores. Por ejemplo, si el usuario escribe "5 10 2 25", la lista que obtienes con tu código sería  `[[5], [1, 0], [2], [2, 5]]` en vez de `[[5, 10], [2, 25]]` que creo que era la idea...

Comment: ejem: 1er input 2 20, 2do 3 15, 3er NULL. Se ingresa por parejas 1 multiplicador y el puntaje sacado por cada input.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo claro aún cómo es el input del programa, pues tal como lo tienes la variable `puntaje_int` estaría compuesta de sub-listas que no son necesariamente de longitud 2. Me explico, tú estás troceando el `input()` por los espacios, por lo que si el usuario teclea por ejemplo `"50 1 25 2 10 1"`, el `split()` producirá los trozos `["50", "1", "25", "2", "10", "1"]` y el bucle que haces a continuación para iterar por cada uno de esos trozos obtendría cada digito por separado por lo que acabarías en `puntaje_int` con una lista tal que así:

```
[[5, 0], [1], [2, 5], [2], [1, 0], [1]]
```

que no creo que sea lo que pretendes, pues alguna de las sublistas tienen dos elementos, otras tienen uno... yo creo que tú querrías obtener:

```
[[50, 1], [25, 2], [10, 1]]
```

Pero al margen de esto, supongamos que tienes una función que se llama `obtener_lista_de_numeros()` que le pregunta al usuario, lo trocea como tenga que trocearlo y te retorna una lista con 6 elementos, cada uno de los cuales es una parejas de números.

Y lo que quieres es ir restando a `p1` los productos de los elementos 0, 1 y 2 de esa lista y "a la vez" a `p2` los productos de los elementos 3, 4 y 5 de esa lista, deteniéndose tan pronto como una de las dos variables llegue a cero.

El enfoque entonces es diferente al de tu anterior pregunta, y ahora la función `sumprod()` ya no es de utilidad. En su lugar simplemente vamos multiplicando parejas de números y restándolas donde corresponda, así:

```
p1 = 501
p2 = 501

while p1 != 0 or p2 != 0:
    puntaje_int = obtener_lista_de_numeros()
    for i in range(3):        # Repetir 3 veces
      a, b = puntaje_int[i]   # sacar los números a muliplicar
      p1 -= a*b               # para restárselos a p1
      a, b = puntaje_int[i+3] # Ahora los que hay que restar a p2
      p2 -= a*b

if p1 <= 0:
    print("Gano",jugadores[0]+"! Felicidades")

if p2 <= 0:
    print("Gano",jugadores[1]+"! Felicidades")
```

Sólo queda escribir la función `obtener_lista_de_numeros()` que tal como tú la tenías sería así:

```
def obtener_lista_de_numeros():
    puntaje = input().replace("DOUBLE","50").replace("SINGLE","25").replace("BULL","1").replace("NULL","0 0").split(" ")
    puntaje_int = [[int(elem) for elem in lista] for lista in puntaje]
    return puntaje_int
```

...pero como dije al principio sospecho que está mal.