# Calcular porcentaje de un valor dentro de un diccionario PYTHON

Tags: python, diccionarios

¡Hola! Estoy iniciándome en Python y me ha surgido un ejercicio que tengo que resolver, pero no consigo encontrar la manera.

El ejercicio me pide que, dentro de un diccionario, incremente el precio en un 50% de tres enteros que forman parte del Valor de una de las Claves.

El código es el siguiente:

```
productos = { 'id':[1,2,3], 
             'nombre':['Arduino', 'RPi', 'Print 3D'], 
             'precio': [30, 70, 300]
            }
```

Tendría que encontrar la manera de incrementar en un 50% los valores de [30, 70, 300]
(Se supone que aun no podemos usar bucles ni condicionales, pero sí la instrucción **for**.

La duda es cómo calcular el 50% de cada uno de manera que, al imprimir por pantalla de nuevo el dic. los precios ya se muestren actualizados (obviamente se puede hacer directamente cambiando el valor, pero entiendo que la gracia del ejercicio es implementar una manera de calcularlo automáticamente). Llevo muy poco con esto y estaba intentando cosas de este tipo, pero no es la manera está claro:

```
productos = { 'id':[1,2,3], 
         'nombre':['Arduino', 'RPi', 'Print 3D'], 
         'precio': [30, 70, 300] 
        }
for x in productos.values():
    productos['precio'][30, 70, 300] = ((x * 50)/100)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda? ¿Cómo acceder a los números? ¿Cómo calcular el 50% de cada uno? ¿Cómo iterar? Plantea el código que has intentado hasta el momento para que veamos dónde te has atascado. Y cómo es eso de que no puedes usar bucles pero sí la instrucción `for`? Un `for` es un bucle...

Comment: Sin bucles significa que deberás actualizar cada valor de forma independiente: `productos['precio'][0] = productos['precio'][0] * 1.5` y así con cada uno.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a los dos por la rápida respuesta! Patricio Moracho creo que es lo que tú me comentas. Yo estaba complicándome la vida tratando de encontrar una manera de hacerlo de golpe. Pero va a ser lo que dices :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como crear un programa que multiplique matrices?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61810/como-crear-un-programa-que-multiplique-matrices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por ayudarte a comprender un poco mejor la sintaxis (lo que te servirá para futuros ejercicios).

`productos` es un diccionario. Los diccionarios tienen valores almacenados en *claves*. Las claves en tu caso son `"id"`, `"nombre"` y `"precio"`. Para acceder al valor correspondiente puedes hacer `productos["nombre"]` por ejemplo.

En tu caso resulta que los valores son listas. Por ejemplo, el valor asociado a `productos["nombre"]` es la lista `['Arduino', 'RPi', 'Print 3D']`. Para acceder a un elemento de una lista pones entre corchetes la posición que ocupa, numerándolas desde cero. Así `lista[0]` sería el primer elemento.

Juntando ambas cosas, puedes acceder al primer nombre poniendo `productos["nombre"][0]`

Los diccionarios también tienen algunos métodos, como `.keys()`, `.values()` o `.items()`. Cuando haces `productos.keys()` obtienes solo las claves del diccionario ("id", "nombre", o "precio"). Cuando haces `productos.values()` obtienes sólo los valores (que en este caso como vimos son listas). El orden en que obtendrás las claves o los valores no está especificado (salvo a partir de python 3.7, en el que coincidirán con el orden en que fueron creadas las claves del diccionario). Finalmente si haces `product.items()` obtendrás parejas (clave, valor).

Una vez tenemos estas cosas claras, podemos abordar tu código y entender por qué estaba mal:

### Análisis del código

```
for x in productos.values():
    productos['precio'][30, 70, 300] = ((x * 50)/100)
```

Esto para empezar es un bucle, y decías que no te estaba permitido usarlos. Aunque por otro lado decías que un `for` sí que estaba permitido (cosa que no entiendo, ya que el `for x in ...` es una forma de bucle).

En todo caso, estás usando `productos.values()`, por lo que obtendrás en cada iteración uno de los valores asociados a *cada una de las claves* del diccionario. Es decir:

1. En la primera iteración `x` tomará como valor `[1,2,3]`, pues ese es el valor correspondiente a la primera clave del diccionario.
2. En la segunda iteración `x` tomará el valor `['Arduino', 'RPi', 'Print 3D']` (correspondiente a la segunda clave del diccionario)
3. En la tercera y última iteración `x` tomará el valor `[30, 70, 300]`

Consecuencia: `x` no es cada uno de los precios, como aparentemente pensabas. Por tanto cuando vayas a hacer la operación `((x * 50)/100)` habrá errores, pues `x` es una lista y multiplicar una lista por 50 no hace lo que esperas (replica 50 veces sus contenidos), y dividirla por 100 dará un error pues esa operación no está definida para listas.

Además, el resultado estás intentando asignarlo a:

```
     productos['precio'][30, 70, 300]
```

lo que tampoco tiene sentido según vimos al principio, ya que `productos['precio']` es una lista con tres elementos por lo que solo puedes acceder al elemento `[0]`, al `[1]` o al `[2]`, pero nunca al `[30]` y menos aún al `[30, 70, 300]` (estarías usando aquí tres índices)

#### Como hacerlo bien

Una forma obvia y sin bucles es elemento a elemento:

```
productos["precio"][0] = productos["precio"][0] * 1.5
productos["precio"][1] = productos["precio"][1] * 1.5
productos["precio"][2] = productos["precio"][2] * 1.5
```

Una sintaxis más corta es `productos["precio"][0] *= 1.5` (que multiplica ese valor por 1.5 y lo almacena en el mismo sitio), y análogamente para los elementos `[1]` y `[2]`.

Usando un bucle, podrías iterar por los índices 0, 1, 2 y acceder a los elementos de la lista de precios:

```
for i in range(3):
  productos["precio"][i] *= 1.5
```

Y para que sea más general, en vez de `3` puedes poner `len(productos["precio"])`

Por último, Python admite también una sintaxis llamada *comprensión de listas* que es otra forma de bucle `for` pero formando parte de una expresión en lugar de ser una sentencia. No sé si te lo habrán explicado, pero por si acaso te lo pongo también:

```
productos["precio"] = [x*1.5 for x in productos["precio"]]
```

Aqui la asignación se produce en una sola línea. En la clave "precio" del diccionario almacenas una lista nueva (que sustituye a la que había). Esa lista se construye multiplicando por 1.5 cada uno de los elementos de la lista original.

Comment: ¡WOW! Darte las gracias en este caso es quedarse muuuy corto. Con la explicación que me das me ha quedado bastante más claro de lo que lo tenía con la explicación del curso que estoy haciendo. Lo dicho, un millón de gracias no, mil millones de gracias. Ahora entiendo lo que estaba haciendo mal.